# c programming Ascii values

Tags: c, char, ascii

Let us say that the English alphabets A to Z has value start from 1. A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 and so on. Write a program which calls a function which accepts the name of a person which is constant character array and returns an integer value with sum of the Alphapets. What is the benefit of passing the name of the person as const char array?

Comment: Well, how else you would pass a read-only string?

Comment: this is not dooing YOUR homework. please show us, what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: We can greatly simplify this program by giving `A` a value of 65 instead of 1.

Comment: A=65 is only in ASCII (okay, is so asked), but you have take care of EBCDIC also :-)

Comment: what value would you give the name "Noël"

Comment: @PeterMiehle But the question has Ascii in the title. Anyway, if you have multiple encodings to consider, using lookup tables might be simpler.

Comment: A local variable might disappear or could be over-written after use, so you will need to make it persisting and something that could not be over-written. So, you make it as READ_ONLY and then pass it to your function with "const" keyword.

Comment: @PeterMiehle Also, the `ë` has value 171 in the OPs original concept. Unless you want to be convert to uppercase, which the OP seems to want, then it would be 139.

Comment: I'm more concerned about names like Billy-Bob, which would have negative characters. Can the program handle that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help link on what sort of questions to ask and how to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose somebody else provides me a function that takes non-const `char *` and does the job. What the function is actually implemented is like this:

```
int get_int_sum(char *name)
{
    int sum;
    //codes to calculate sum of alphas
    name[0] += 1;
    //continue
    return sum;
}
```

When I call the function using

```
char my_name[] = "Yu Hao";
int reuslt = get_int_sum(my_name);
```

Even if I got the result I want, `my_name` is changed to `"Zu Hao"` without my notice. However, if a function has a prototype of

```
int get_int_sum(const char*name)
```

I am sure that the string I passed will not be modified.

Comment: @MrLister Maybe it's changed to `"Zu Hao"` instead, since we add one to the character value and not subtract one. But who cares? The point is that it could be changed, and we don't want that. Furthermore, why would it "return garbage"?

Comment: @MrLister It's pointless to engage in a debate about the modified string, since the C standard doesn't guarantee that the char code of `Z` comes after that of `Y`. Also, what do you **honestly** think the `// codes to calculate sum of alphas` part stands for in the example?

Comment: @Mr Lister Right. but that's clearly a typo.

Comment: @YuHao Sorry, but as I said, the OP is a newbie, and it might be clearly a typo to you and me, but it would be very confusing to a beginner. Anyway, you corrected the error, so I can safely upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is that elements in a array are protected from changing its value.
For example, here is simple code.

```
int Your_function(const char * a)
{
    a[3]    =   'A'; // this statement causes compile error.
    // do something
    return 0;
}
```